# JavaFX, ccs border с анимацией

Tags: java, css, javafx

Имею простейший BorderPane с рамкой, заданной с помощью таблицы стилей css:

```
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-border-style: dashed ");
```

Рамка чёрная, пунктирная и толщиной в 2 пикселя. Есть варианты анимировать эту рамку? Заставить моргать и/или двигаться по/против часовой? Обычные способы ccs не работают, либо я не верно пробовал. Благодарю.

Comment: а возможность есть работать с svg ?я в java Ноль с большой буквы

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский сам не знаю об этой особенности,пишу на java по нужде. Но тут(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436274/svg-image-in-javafx-2-2) говорят, что можно вроде бы.

Comment: на svg много что можно анимировать реализовать ... на css некоторые вещи не возможно сделать .. извените

Comment: из коробки векторной графики нет в javaFX, где-то на гитхабе были ухищрения. Заставить моргать думаю можно можно меняя стили в анимации.

Comment: @Maxim, уже думал об этом, скорее всего да, менять стиль + таймер

Comment: @Range только не таймер, а что-то вроде `Timeline Animation`. Вероятно надо просто менять цвет на прозрачный, чтобы разметка не начала прыгать.